# Checkbox is checked or not in mvc

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, checkbox, checked

```
$("#Month option:selected").val();
```

By this we can get the selected value in our DDL. same as this how can we get weather CheckBox is checked or not. How can i do this?

```
<input id="Baruc" type="checkbox" value="true" name="Baruc" data-val-required="The Baruc field is required." data-val="true" onchange="showlabel();">
```

for this checkbox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check checkbox checked property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You need to use `.length` for checked elements.

```
if($("#Baruc:checked").length){
  //checkbox is checked
}
```

**Solution 2:**

also you can use `.is()` method with `:checked` selector:

```
if($("#Baruc").is(":checked")){
  //checkbox is checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to check whether a checkbox is checked or not you can try using `.is()` as shown :-

jQuery syntax.

```
$('#Baruc').is(':checked') // it returns bool if checkbox is checked it will return 'true' otherwise 'false'.
```

**Edit :-** there must be a colon before checked

Javascipt syntax.

```
if(document.getElementById("Baruc").checked)
{
   //checkbox is checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('#Baruc').is('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass `this` in your onchange function:

```
onchange="showlabel(this);
```

now in your method you can use this:

```
function showlabel(elem){
    alert(elem.checked); // true if checked false if unchecked
}
```

```js
function showlabel(elem){ alert(elem.checked);}
```

```html
<input id="Baruc" type="checkbox" value="true" name="Baruc" data-val-required="The Baruc field is required." data-val="true" onchange="showlabel(this);">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the checkbox is checked or not by the given code :

```
$(‘#CHECKBOXID’).is(‘:checked’);
```

if any confusions then use the below link :

https://codeupweb.wordpress.com/2017/07/11/check-if-checkbox-if-checked-using-jquery/